# How do I get the back button to go back multiple pages in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on an application and I need the back button to go back multiple pages. I am familiar with the history.back function as shown below.

```
//go back to the last view
$rootScope.goBack = function(){
    history.back();
  }
```

However, this only goes back one page. Is there anyway for the history to go back further than one step? If so, how can I implement this?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I figured I would also share that you can you use the back() feature not only in the html but also in your controller by using $rootScope.back(-2);

Comment: Look into angular's [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tell it how far to go back:

```
$rootScope.goBack = function(){
    history.go(-3);
}
```

It's really as simple as that.

Comment: Wow you are genius! Thank you.

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept the answer.  And, you're welcome.